# Create model using Abstract model with approve system

Tags: django, django-models, django-contenttypes

I'm going to use https://github.com/ghdpro/animesuki/tree/master/animesuki/history and modify it under myself, but I stopped at one point which I am not able to jump with my skills ..

The point is that if I am a superuser, or I have the permissions given in this model, it adds to my main model Movie record, and if it adds without permissions, it is added only to ChangeRequest, my question is how to do that after the approved added to the main Movie model, and when accepting and changing the field, updated the data in the given object.
It works more or less as I want, but I can not jump this step ..

I do not need the whole solution, but only tips, or some source code from which I can learn how to do that

EDIT:

```
class Movie(HistoryModel):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    slug = extension_fields.AutoSlugField(populate_from='title', blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=2000, default='', blank=True)
    picture = ImageField(upload_to=user_directory_path, default='img/movie/default/brak_obrazka.jpg', blank=True)
    pub_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    mpaa = models.CharField(max_length=5, choices=AGE_GROUP, default='PG-13')
    movie_time = models.CharField(max_length=20, default='90')
```

My question was, currently normal user adding Movie is only added to the ChangeRequest model in the above given link, after changing from Pending = Approved, how to add this model to Movie, and then if changes are added to update the given model

Comment: Um.. I don't understand your question. Can you describe more about your problem? Also can you upload your models, too?

Comment: I added edit to my post, look it

Comment: Ok thanks I will see it.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't see whole code, but I think you should look `HistoryModel`

As you can see [here](https://github.com/ghdpro/animesuki/blob/master/animesuki/history/models.py#L346), `HistoryModel` has `save()` and `save_related()` method.

You should see here to understand what's going on underneath.

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self._cr = self.create_changerequest()
    if self.self_approve and self.sanity_checks and self.sanity_checks_extra:
        # Approve immediately if right conditions are met
        self._cr.status = ChangeRequest.Status.APPROVED
    self._cr.save()
    # Save actual model instance if: ChangeRequest object was saved -and- the request was self-approved
    # (ChangeRequest object will not have been saved if data was not altered)
    if self._cr.pk:
        self.log()
        if self._cr.status == ChangeRequest.Status.APPROVED:
            super().save(*args, **kwargs)
            self._cr.set_object(self)
            self._cr.save()
            # Generate message
            verb = {ChangeRequest.Type.ADD: 'Added',
                    ChangeRequest.Type.MODIFY: 'Updated'}  # DELETE or RELATED requests shouldn't be handled by save()
            self.add_message(messages.SUCCESS, verb[self._cr.request_type], self._cr.object_type, self._cr.object_str)
        elif self._cr.status == ChangeRequest.Status.PENDING:
            self.add_message_pending()
    # Reset cached property
    if hasattr(self, 'has_pending'):
        delattr(self, 'has_pending')

def save_related(self, formset):
    self._cr = self.create_changerequest(request_type=ChangeRequest.Type.RELATED)
    self._cr.related_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(formset.model)
    self._cr.data_revert = formset_data_revert(formset)
    self._cr.data_changed = formset_data_changed(formset)
    if self.self_approve and self.sanity_checks and self.sanity_checks_extra:
        # Approve immediately if right conditions are met
        self._cr.status = ChangeRequest.Status.APPROVED
    self._cr.save()
    # Save formset if: ChangeRequest object was saved -and- the request was self-approved
    # (ChangeRequest object will not have been saved if data was not altered)
    if self._cr.pk:
        self.log()
        if self._cr.status == ChangeRequest.Status.APPROVED:
            formset.save()
            # Generate message(s)
            for obj in formset.new_objects:
                self.add_message(messages.SUCCESS, 'Added', self._cr.related_type, obj)
                self.log('Add', format_object_str(self._cr.related_type, obj, obj.pk))
            for obj in formset.changed_objects:
                self.add_message(messages.SUCCESS, 'Updated', self._cr.related_type, obj)
                self.log('Modify', format_object_str(self._cr.related_type, obj, obj.pk))
            for obj in formset.deleted_objects:
                self.add_message(messages.SUCCESS, 'Deleted', self._cr.related_type, obj)
                self.log('Delete', format_object_str(self._cr.related_type, obj, obj.pk))
            # Refresh data_changed: any new instances should now have a pk set
            self._cr.data_changed = formset_data_revert(formset)
            self._cr.save()
        elif self._cr.status == ChangeRequest.Status.PENDING:
            self.add_message_pending()
    # Reset cached property
    if hasattr(self, 'has_pending'):
        delattr(self, 'has_pending')
```

Comment: yea i now about this, but i dont know what i should add to add model in ContentType model, bc i dont want using it for only Movie Model :>